# Display ngModel Object In Html Template

Tags: angular, hyperledger

Here is the `.html` code

```
[ngModel]="offers" formControlName="offers"
```

It Output: **[object Object]**

How could I got the **offers** array value??

Comment: if its an array you need to use ng-repeat="offer in offers" then use offer in form control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
{{ offers | json }}
```

Use `pipe` as `json` on html page.

Comment: Using **[ngModel]={{ offers | json }}** instead of **[ngModel]="offers"**??

Comment: No, on html page inside `div`. like `<div>{{offer | json}}</div>` . how are you getting `[Object Object]` in your app ? it must be when you are rendering on `html` page

Comment: Yes, I am getting **[object Object]**. :(